# Out of memory error when inserting more records(nearly 1,00,000 records) into database

Tags: android

I am inserting 1,00,000 records into databse through background thread.at this time when I want load Ui screens I am getting Out of memory error.For example When the Heap size is 5 MB and 4MB is allotted to background threads,2 MB is required for loading UI screen.So in this scenario I am getting Out of memory issue.Please tell me what I need to do here to fix out of memory issue.

Comment: Why do you need so much memory in your background thread? You should be holding one record at a time in memory. (Not that it matters particularly, but is it 1,000,000 records or 100,000 records?)

Comment: I am not inserting one record at a time.I am inserting 1000 records at a time.in this way I am inserting 1,00,000 records.I am following this link http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/ for inserting more records at a time for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting 100 at a time instead of 1,000 at a time. That should cut your background thread's memory usage by quite a bit.

If your records are coming from the server as XML, don't use a DOM parser; it is a memory hog. Use a SAX, StAX, or pull parser instead.

Finally, be sure that you aren't keeping references to objects that you don't need once the records are inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But if I insert 100 at a time I will take some more time.

Comment: I am getting response as Json string.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna - Better that it take some more time than it not work at all. :)

Comment: So do we have any other better solution for this in android?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use less memory...

Those 1,000,000 records come from somewhere. Don't keep them in memory all at once - if you read them, write them to the database as you read them - one chunk at a time (say, 1,000 at a time?). If you generate them, don't generate all of them at once, but rather - a chunk at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I am getting 1000 records from server and inserting 1000 records at atime by following this link http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/ here I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure you're removing all references to the previous 1000 records before processing the next batch? If you keep a reference somewhere, you'll run out of memory. Do you write to the database each time, for example?

Comment: I am sure I removing all 1000 records

Comment: Do you get the exception while inserting the first batch?

Comment: The out of memory error, when do you get it? During which batch?

Comment: I am getting this error while loading other UI screens during databse insertions.

Comment: OK, try first loading the UI screens, then start the database operation.

Comment: I am using Tabs concept.I have 5 tabs.I am loading each tab when user clicks that particular tab.I am unable to trace when the user selects that tab.

Comment: You just need this for testing. Have the 5th tab start the operation, run the app and open all tabs in a row.

Comment: Ok thanks for your responses.I will try this and I will let you know.

Answer (score -1):

Insert all your records from seperate thread different from main thread or process .Use IntentService class in android for inserting large number of entries in your database which does not effect your UI. for ex:

```
 public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
            EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;
            SQLiteDatabase dbx ;
            SQLiteDatabase rdbx;
            ContentValues values;

            public BackgroundService() {
                super("BackgroundService");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                eventsData=new EventDataSQLHelper(BackgroundService.this);
                values=new ContentValues();
                dbx = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();    
                rdbx = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
                for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
        dbx.insert("tablename", null,values);

        }


                dbx.close();


            }


            }
```

Comment: I am using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for running threads

Comment: How is this going to decrease memory usage?